# How to view attribute table in layer within ArcGIS Server map service?

Tags: arcgis-server, fields-attributes

I'm new to ArcGIS Server and am trying to publish layers within an mxd to ArcGIS Server. When I bring the published map service back into Arc there is no Open Attribute Table option although I am able to identify the data. Is there away of displaying the attribute table?

Answer (score 5):

Attribute table you can not see in the map service..You have to go back ArcMap and then you can see the correct information..

OR you can fire query through the REST url

OR if you need to create web application in that you can verify the correct information through identify option (If you are using ArcGIS Server 10.0)